# Laravel- I need help passing user_id to tasks_table in SQL database Error: Call to undefined method App\\User::id()

Tags: mysql, laravel, authentication, task

I am a student still new to figuring out all of this Laravel stuff. I have been stuck trying to make my tasks pass the user_id to my SQL database in the store method. I've tried about 1000 different ways with no luck.

The current Error: Call to undefined method App\User::id(). I noticed that other posts don't seem to have the 2 \ after App in their errors. Can't see why it is doing that.

I've posted all of the code in case someone gets any help from it. Any help would be supperrrr appreciated and if you need more from me, let me know.

This is myTaskController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\User;


class TaskController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return response(Task::latest()->get(), 200);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'text' => 'required',
            'finished' => 'required|boolean',
        ]);

        $user = Auth::user()->id();
        $task = Task::create($data, $user);

        return response($task, 201);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Task  $task
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Task $task)
    {
        return response($task, 200);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Task  $task
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Task $task)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'text' => 'required',
            'finished' => 'required|boolean',
        ]);

        $task->update($data);

        return response($task, 200);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Task $task
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function destroy(Task $task)
    {
        $task->delete();

        return response('Deleted Succesfully', 200);
    }
}
```

This is my Task Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'text',
        'finished',
        'user_id'

    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'finished' => 'boolean',
    ];

    public function tasks(){
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

This is my User Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Task;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function tasks(){
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }
}
```

Tasks Table Schema

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->longText('text');
        $table->boolean('finished')->default(false);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

User Table Schema

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can post the db table schemas as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changed your code little:

**Task Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'text',
        'finished',
        'user_id'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'finished' => 'boolean',
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

**TaskController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Task;
use Auth;
use DB;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return response(Task::latest()->get(), 200);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'text' => 'required',
            'finished' => 'required|boolean'
        ]);

        $task = Task::create([
            'text' => $request->text,
            'finished' => $request->finished,
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
        ]);

        return response($task, 201);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Task  $task
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Task $task)
    {
        return response($task, 200);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Task  $task
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Task $task)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'text' => 'required',
            'finished' => 'required|boolean',
        ]);

        $task->update([
            'text' => $request->text,
            'finished' => $request->finished,
        ]);

        return response($task, 200);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Task $task
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function destroy(Task $task)
    {
        $task->delete();

        return response('Deleted Successfully', 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes I have tried that, still the same error :( I'll edit the above to reflect that.

Comment: whats your primary key on user table ?

Comment: I believe this is what you're asking? $table->increments('id');

Comment: yeah, then its id. what if you create the task data and append user_id index manually? i am giving an example in my answer

Comment: It still has the same error. It might be in my model possibly? It says line 50 so probably the controller though. It's being stubborn lol.

Comment: Where you using App\\User::id() ?

Comment: I did a directory search and all that comes up are the storage log errors. It's super odd.

Comment: did you removed tasks method from task model ? and let me know when actually this exception thrown?

Comment: I get the error when I try to add a task. It works fine if I add nullable to the user_id it just doesn't seem to like the user_id. I tried removing tasks. still nothing.

Comment: what did you see when you dd($data) after $data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id(); line

Comment: You are a lifesaver!! Thank-you so so much!

Comment: i did not noticed you just creating the data from validation rules returned data :P . all of your form data is inside $request. you are welcome :)